Google Sheets API 404 error: "Requested Entity Was Not Found" Uncaught Google\Service\Exception
first let me say i apologize if this is an easy solution, i've never used google api or anything similar, as well as i'm new to php
i'm currently trying to read a spreadsheet using google sheets api and just print it out. i think everything looks fine, but when i run it, it gives me this error:
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Google\Service\Exception: {

"error": {
"code": 404,
"message": "Requested entity was not found.",
"errors": [
{
"message": "Requested entity was not found.",
"domain": "global",
"reason": "notFound"
}
],
"status": "NOT_FOUND"
}
}
here is my php file:
        require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

        $client = new \Google_Client();
        $client->setApplicationName('Sheets Test');
        $client->setScopes([\Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS]);
        $client->setAccessType('offline');
        $client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/credentials.json');
        $service = new \Google_Service_Sheets($client);
        $spreadsheetId = "1sefMmSCVnQRMVFuG8l5SKx7phpD2vvmwzq7opsgyuebYIU";
        $range = "currentRatings!A2:C4";
        $response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
        $values = $response->getValues();
        if(empty($values)){
            print "No data found. \n";
        } else {
             $mask = "%10s %-10s $s\n";
             foreach($values as $row){
                echo sprintf($mask, $row[2], $row[1], $row[0]);
            }
        } 

as shown above, i did connect a credentials file which is the same service account that the sheet is shared to. i also know that the problem occurs/starts at this line:
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
here's what i've tried:

double checking the sheet id
downgrading the version of google api via composer
changing the "$range" values (nothing changed, even when i changed the name of the sheet to an incorrect name)
creating a new service account in google console
making sure the sheet is shared to the service account


Are you using service account?

In the current stage, it seems that the length of the spreadsheet ID is 44. But, in your script, if you are using your Spreadsheet ID as 1sefMmSCVnQRMVFuG8l5SKx7phpD2vvmwzq7opsgyuebYIU of $spreadsheetId = "1sefMmSCVnQRMVFuG8l5SKx7phpD2vvmwzq7opsgyuebYIU";, I'm worried that the length is 47. Is this related to the reason for your current issue? But, you say double checking the sheet id. So, if I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

i can’t believe i didn’t see this, you’re right, the id is longer than it should be. i have no clue how i got 47 characters but thank you so much! when i was checking the id i only checked the front and back of the url

okay so i found out that my id was too long, i was probably accidentally typing in it at some point which caused the error. i did check the id, but i only checked the front and back of the id.
